# partition theory: meet the COP

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, soft-question, generating-functions, partitions

Recall  that $(a;q)_0:=1,\,(a;q)_n=(1-a)(1-aq)(1-aq^2)\cdots(1-aq^{n-1})$ and
$(a;q)_{\infty}=(1-a)(1-aq)(1-aq^2)\cdots$. Let's introduce the following (generalized) concept.

A *colored overpartition* (COP) is a partition where the last occurrence of each distinct number may receive any one of $c$ colors. The number of such partitions of $n$ we denote by $\overline{p}_c(n)$. For example, the $8$ COP partitions of $n=3$ with $c=2$ colors are:
$$3,\, \overline{3}, \, 2+1, \, \overline{2}+1, \, 2+\overline{1}, \, \overline{2}+\overline{1}, \, 1+1+1, \, 1+1+\overline{1}.$$
**Note.** In the literature, (i) ordinary partitions $p(n)=\overline{p}_1(n)$; (ii)  overpartitions $\overline{p}(n)=\overline{p}_2(n)$.

> **Question.** Does this generating function hold true?
>   $$\sum_{n\geq0}\overline{p}_c(n)q^n=\frac{((1-c)q;q)_{\infty}}{(q;q)_{\infty}}.$$

Comment: Just a typographical suggestion, `$COP$` uses mathemarics spacing for what is an acronym, so looks wrong. I think the small-caps `\textsc{COP}`, italic `\textit{COP}` or just plain `COP` would look better.

Comment: @J.J.Green: Thanks, I edited as such. How about now?

Comment: Google search returned only 6 hits regarding "colored overpartition". One of them is your paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.4045 where this question goes under Theorem 12.1. This shows that you already have a proof.

Comment: @Nemo: No, I don't have a proof. In the preprint you saw it should read "conjectures" instead of "theorem". Sorry, it appeared misleading.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan, that looks much better to me!

Comment: For overpartitions overlined parts form a partition into distinct parts and the non-overlined parts form an ordinary partition, therefore the generating function is $\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1+q^n}{1-q^n}$. In analogy with this well known case, for $\textrm{COP}$ with $c$ colors, the non-overlined parts form an ordinary partition and the overlined parts form  a partition into distinct parts such that each part can take one of $c-1$ colors. So it is not surprising that generating function is $\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1+(c-1)q^n}{1-q^n}$.

Comment: (1) it is not very surprising, yet we need a proof; (2) in the literature hits, there are different flavors of COP. But, the one here is different from them all because while others considered allowing coloring to all parts, in the present case we only color selected parts. This should be made clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than coloring the last occurrence of each distinct number, we
can equivalently for each part $i$ color all the $i$'s with the same
color. Thus
  $$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\bar{p}_c(n)q^n = \prod_{i\geq
  1}(1+c(q^i+q^{2i}+q^{3i}+\cdots)) $$
  $$ = \prod_{i\geq 1}\frac{1+(c-1)q^i}{1-q^i}. $$